# New JQuery Mobile Version Affecting Page Transition?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Page1" >

   <!-- Footer here -->
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="id-footer1">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#Page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#Page2" data-transition="pop">Page2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="Page2" >

   <!-- Footer here -->
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="id-footer1">
         <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#Page1" >Page1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#Page2" data-transition="pop"class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div><!-- /footer -->
   </div><!-- /page -->
```

The above codes will work if I use the following scripts. That is, Page 1 will have the Slide effect and Page 2 the Pop effect.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I used the following, the slide effect and pop effect are gone.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Seems like the new JQM version has affected the page transition or am I missing something? Can anybody confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: Which device are you using for testing?

Comment: I am using my Android Sensation phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the transitions section in the [announcement of 1.1.0](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/04/13/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0/):

> Unfortunately, after a ton of work, we’ve determined that it’s not possible to dumb down
>   page transitions enough to get acceptable performance in Android 2.x, even on a newer device
>   like a Nexus S running 2.3. After a lot of deliberation, we’ve decided to use a feature test
>   for 3D transforms to target transitions: if a browser passes, it will see the full range of
>   transitions. By default, if a browser fails this 3D test, they will fall back to a fade
>   transition, regardless of the transition specified. All Android 1.x-2.x devices fail this
>   test but Android 3.x and 4.x pass. The fallback behavior for each transition is completely
>   configurable if you want to change this behavior.

If your testing browser doesn't support 3D transforms you will get a fade transition.